# Sql Server 2012 Restoring Master and Migrating a server

Tags: sql-server, migration

I am migrating an entire SQL Server instance with 10 databases on it.

It has many jobs and users. What is best practice regarding the master database? Should I backup and restore this too, or script the users and jobs?

Also, is there another better way to migrate an entire SQL Server instance with all of its databases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont see a need (nor I do it when migrating server) to do a restore of master (or system databases) on the destination server - unless you are trying to achieve something that you have not mentioned in your question.

I find it easy to use [sp_help_revlogin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992) to just move logins from one server to another.

so your migration steps would be like below: Server A = Old server ; Server B is NEW server.

- script out logins from server A.
- script out jobs from server A.
- Backup and restore databases from Server A to Server B.
- Recreate logins scripted out from server A to Server B.
- Sync up orphan users (if any).
- Recreate jobs scripted out from server A to server B. Make sure to move packages if any as well.
- change compatibility level (if moving from lower to higher version).
- run DBCC UPDATEUSAGE
- update stats on all tables with fullscan
- Run `DBCC CHECKDB ('<db_name_goes_here>' ) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS,NO_INFOMSGS, DATA_PURITY`

You can refer to my script at https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41179/8783 (**make sure you do a backup restore and not detach/attach method** - now learned it !!).

Comment: agreed. restoring an old `master` to a fresh install is bad juju

Answer (score 3):

If you want to move the entire instance you can backup and restore the system databases, but make sure you get more than just `master`.  `msdb` and `model` are also important.  In fact `msdb` will contain all of your jobs and any ssis packages that you have stored in the instance.  `master` primarily will be your logins and list of databases.  model is the template for tempdb.  If you've never made any changes to it you can probably skip it, but it doesn't hurt to bring it along also.

Here is some light reading on the subject for you.

[System Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178028.aspx)
[Back Up and Restore of System Databases (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190190.aspx)

Also I should point out that you can only restore `master` and possible `msdb` on an instance that is the exact same build number.  One way around this is to create your new instance, shut it down, and copy the master.mdf, mastlog.ldf, MSDBData.mdf and MSDBLog.ldf files to the locations they exist for the instance (copy/rename the originals first of course).  Once you bring the instance back up you will need to re-patch back to your original level.

Comment: Should SMK be restored before or after restoring the master db?

Comment: 99% certain it should go after.

Comment: After I restore the master db, I can see all my user dbs in management studio, but can't open them because their mdf/ldf is missing. To make them work is it OK to copy the original mdf/ldf over? Or do I restore user dbs from backup?

Comment: Hi any comment on above?

Answer (score 1):

Take a full backup of the master database from the source instance. Stop the destination/target instance's agent service, and start the  instance in single user mode, and restore the master database using the WITH REPLACE hint via the sqlcmd command line utility.

If, for some reason you cannot start the target database instance in single user mode, then scripting your jobs and users would be the better option.