# How to update ALL folder locations after server upgrade?

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

I recently upgraded my server from SQL 2019 to SQL 2022 (first time ever in-place upgrade, after all these years). I'm somewhat disappointed, however, to find that the server is still pointing to the old folder hierarchy:

`.\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\*`

It seems the upgrade didn't adjust this.

I'm finding plenty of discussion on reconfiguring a subset of these (Data, Logs, Backup, etc.), but nothing on how to redefine EVERYTHING to point to a newly-created `MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER` hierarchy.

How can I do this? Is such a move even advisable? There's no solid reason, I suppose... it's just that it's itching me something awful. A 16 server pointing to 15 folders? Heresy!

Comment: if everything is working fine, why would you take the risk of changing it? I know this sounds mediocre, but that is my take.  Check [dbatools](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47526/22336) could help.

Comment: @MarcelloMiorelli — _"If it ain't broke, don't fix it."_ I know, I know—I'm starting to lean in that direction. For sure, though... no more in-place upgrades. It was easy, yes, but the unintended consequences outweigh that. I've learnt my lesson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, DBAs often avoid in-place upgrades to avoid artifacts of the older version such as the folder name.

This can be done either with an uninstall/reinstall on the existing machine or with a side-by-side migration to another machine with a fresh install. The latter method guarantees no previous version artifacts, provides an easier backout plan, and an opportunity to upgrade to a newer OS too (admins also commonly avoid in-place OS upgrades).

Comment: Good plan, thanks. BTW, the OS policy has long been my practice—so why not my database as well? That's the new rule, especially after this.